# programmatically factorize a large number

Tags: algorithm, math, factorization

Alright, so I have a huge number `f`. This number is just over 100 digits long, actually. I know that the factors are of approximately the same size.

If I have limited resources and time, what language and algorithm should I use? I am including the length of time to code the algorithm in the restricted time.

Thoughts?

EDIT: By limited, I mean in the least amount of time possible.

Comment: @Mysticial amusing, but not helpful.

Comment: Sounds like a good exercise for cloud computing.  This should be easy to run parallel processing against.  (Meets limited time, but maybe not limited resources...)

Comment: @ziesemer interesting thought - how would you go about cloud computing this? I have several servers.

Comment: @tekknolagi I know, that's why it isn't an answer. But I'm serious, even with the [state-of-the-art quadratic sieve algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_sieve), it's gonna take a while.

Comment: @tekknolagi Actually, on second thought. [100 digits isn't that much.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_numbers#RSA-100) I was under the impression that each of the factors were 100 digits each. 100 digits is probably on the upper-end of what's doable on a desktop using the quadratic sieve algorithm.

Comment: Is f a specific number that you could add to the post, or do you mean that you'll have _some_ f with ~100 digits?

Comment: @DSM It is a specific number, but I'd rather not add it. It's part of a puzzle, you see.

Comment: Sorry if my intended humor didn't pass well. I've deleted that comment.

Comment: @Mysticial it did, but I was looking for an answer :P

Comment: @tekknolagi, Mysticial - That's why it was a comment, and not an answer.  :-)

Comment: @tekknolagi - If/when you can, please edit your question to include the number and tag me.  I'd be curious to see how long it would take me to process it on some hardware that I have.  I'm guessing others would be similarly curious.  (I know you told DSM that you can't include it here.)  You could also PM it to me if you wish...

Comment: @ziesemer i will add you when i can. i've been using Pollard's and it's taken over 10 hours, and still not done. Macbook 2.7GHz and my server.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The state-of-the-art prime factorization algorithm is the [quadratic sieve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_sieve) and its variants. For numbers larger than 100 digits, the [number sieve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Number_field_sieve) becomes more efficient.

There's an open-source implementation of it [here](http://www.boo.net/~jasonp/qs.html). It's able to factor a 100 digit number into two roughly equal primes in only [4 hours on a 2.2 GHz AMD Althon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_numbers#RSA-100).

So there's the algorithm and a sample implementation. That might be enough to give you ideas or get you started.

Comment: Do you consider the number field sieve a variant of the quadratic sieve?

Comment: No. But the cut-off threshold between the two is about 100 digits anyway. I'll add that to my answer though. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a good exercise (and possibly a rare good example) for cloud computing.  This should be easy to run parallel processing against.  Divide your pools of factors across each of your processes.

Something like this may prove helpful:  http://blog.controlgroup.com/2010/10/13/hadoop-and-amazon-elastic-mapreduce-analyzing-log-files/  More details at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Hadoop#Hadoop_on_Amazon_EC2.2FS3_services .

(In the past month, I had watched a nice video demonstration of doming something similar to what I'm suggesting here - but of course, now I can't find the link.)

Especially if you don't need to do this programatically, take a look at http://www.alpertron.com.ar/ECM.HTM .  (Linked to from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_sieve.)  Pay particular attention to the notes under "Factoring a number in several machines" on the first link.  (As the source code is available, you could run this is a programatically distributed fashion as well, using Hadoop or the like.)

Comment: What do you mean by `pools of factors`? I only have one number.

Comment: @tekknolagi - you have one number, but many, many possible factors (what you're searching for).

Comment: True, true. Any more detail on the actual splitting of the factorization?

Comment: @tekknolagi - Please see the addition to the end of my answer.

Comment: "pools of factors" is not quite right. For the quadratic sieve it would be pools of polynomials.

Comment: @GregS - Agreed.  My suggestion was for a much more primitive approach (like MVTCplusplus's :-).

Comment: @ziesemer: Not at all, your suggestion is perfectly appropriate to the QS.

Answer (score -2):

```
while (x < Number) {
    if ((Number % x) == 0 ) { 
        cout << x << "*" << Number/x << endl;
        ++x;
    }  
    else ++x;
}
```

Comment: Too bad the OP's #'s won't fit inside of an `int`.

Comment: I'm not sure if you're joking or serious.

Comment: he's not joking.  he is just using compiler that has native support for bigint types, and compiles the code with various optimizations. :)