# How to find the most number of factors in a list of numbers?

Tags: python, factors

Im writing a python program which gets the user to input up to 10 numbers, and the program tells the user which of those numbers has the most amount of factors, for example  out of 25, 38, 49 and 60, it would tell me that 60 has the most factors. How would I go around doing this?

Comment: If *you* are writing the program, why are you asking  *us* to write it? See [ask].

Comment: Break the problem down. How do you enter the numbers? Do you need to store them or process them one by one as entered? How do you find or count the factors of a number? How would you write a function to do it? Etc...

Comment: hey man,  i didnt ask you guys to write it, i was simply just asking for someone to point me in the right direction on how i can approach this

Comment: Hey man, I thought that's exactly what I was doing in my previous comment.

Answer (score 1):

This question has been answered already. Take a look at this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8867991/programatically-factorize-a-large-number).

Basically, you can use some prime factorization algorithm (this post suggests quadratic sieve, I'm not gonna go into the algorithm itself) and get the number of prime factors each of your entered numbers have, and then output the one with the most factors.